# C# form Close message box on button click

Tags: c#, email, cancel-button

Is there a way to get the message box to close and return to the form without it emailing the data?

halfway there atm just need a help with the second if/else if statement. I'm very new to all this.

my code is below :)

```
//Button
    private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string software = null;
        string hardware = null;



        foreach (string s in softwareNeededCheckedListBox.CheckedItems)
        {
            software = software + '\n' + s;
        }

        foreach (string s in hardwareNeededCheckedListBox.CheckedItems)
        {
            hardware = hardware + '\n' + s;
        }

        if (yesRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
           yesRadioButton.Text = "Yes";
            noRadioButton.Text = " ";
        }


        if (noRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
           noRadioButton.Text = "No";
            yesRadioButton.Text = " ";
        }



        if (MessageBox.Show("First name: " + firstNameTextBox.Text + "  " + "Last name: " + lastNameTextBox.Text + "\n" + "\n" +
               "Will be working in " + areaOfTheCompanyComboBox.SelectedItem + "\n" + "\n" +
               "They will need the following software:" + software + "\n" + "\n" +
               "They will need the following hardware:" + hardware + "\n" + "\n" +
               "They will be seated: " + seatingLocationRichTextBox.Text + "\n" + "\n" +
               "Any further Comments: " + notesRichTextBox.Text + "\n" + "\n" +
               "Do they require a phone: " + noRadioButton.Text + yesRadioButton.Text + "\n" + "\n" +
               "Date they start: " + completionDateTimePicker.Text + "\n" + "\n" +
               "Are you happy with the information shown above?" + "\n" + "\n" +
               MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtpserver = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("xxxxx@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("xxxxx@xxxxxx.co.uk");
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
            mail.Body = "First name: " + firstNameTextBox.Text + "  " + "Last name: " + lastNameTextBox.Text + "\n" + "\n" +
                 "Will be working in " + areaOfTheCompanyComboBox.SelectedItem + "\n" + "\n" +
                 "They will need the following software:" + software + "\n" + "\n" +
                 "They will need the following hardware:" + hardware + "\n" + "\n" +
                 "They will be seated: " + seatingLocationRichTextBox.Text + "\n" + "\n" +
                 "Any further Comments: " + notesRichTextBox.Text + "\n" + "\n" +
                 "Do they require a phone: " + noRadioButton.Text + yesRadioButton.Text + "\n" + "\n" +
                 "Date they start: " + completionDateTimePicker.Text;
            smtpserver.Port = 587;
            smtpserver.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("**", "********");
            smtpserver.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("Your Form has been sent ");

        }
```

Comment: What you are doing should be ok... that is: if you press Cancel, then the e-mail is not sent. Your `if` looks right to me. Is it sending even if you click cancel?

Comment: no cancel button doesn't seem to appear that is the problem at the moment, as you have confirmed that my if shuld work :(

Comment: Oh yes, you put a "+" and not a comma, so `MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel` is passed as an addition to the string, not as a parameter to the function.

That was tricky :-)

I've upvoted you, @aiapatag , nice catch

Comment: Ok thanks didn't realise I needed the title :) accepted and will upvote when able :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually forgot you place commas to your `MessageBox.Show` to have the correct arguments/parameters.

```
        if (MessageBox.Show("Body of your message box",
                            "Title Of Your MessageBox",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.OK)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That will only e-mail if the user clicks `OK`.  You can handle the cancel button by using `DialogResult.Cancel`

I would personally put the MessageBox in a `dialogResult` variable. For instance:

```
var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("FIrst name .... ");
```

Then you can check if the user pressed `OK` or `Cancel`

```
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK) {
    // Send the e-mail
} else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel) {
    // Do what you need to do / return to the form.
}
```

To show a messagebox with `OK and Cancel` you need:

```
MessageBox.Show(this, "Message", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
```

Comment: Tried that also bud Ms VS2012 just doesn't seem to want to show the cancel button :(

Comment: @DavidGolding - I have edited my answer to show you the correct syntax for a MessageBox with OK and Cancel